# How could I know my server's operating system?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, webserver

I’m connected to my shared hosting server via ssh, and all I know is that it’s under Linux. 
I tried commands like: `cat /etc/issue/` and `lsb_release -a`
 but got:

```
$ cat /etc/issue/
No such file or directory

$ lsb_release -a
-bash: lsb_release: command not found
```

and `uname -a` only gives : `Linux .......secureserver.net 2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 10 08:57:30 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`gcc -v` gives:

```
Using built-in specs. Target: x86_64-redhat-linux Configured with:
../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man
--infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux Thread model: posix gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)
```

Comment: Every distro has it's own way of figuring out what it is. Might also try doing `cat /etc/*-release` in case it's a RH-oriented distro. First step would be to figure out what package management it's using so as to narrow the field of possibilities.

Comment: cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory

Comment: Actually I take that back, your kernel version has `el6` in it. That means it's either RHEL6 or CentOS 6. Red Hat is the only major distro that I'm aware of that puts their brand in the kernel version string.

Comment: Either they've removed the `/etc/redhat-release` file or something else is amiss: [For example](https://dpaste.de/9bpT)

Comment: Is this a Cisco VM per chance? They use RHEL as their base but for some reason remove random bits of branding out of it (maybe legal reasons I don't know).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know, all I know it's that is a Godaddy shared hosting running Apache.

Comment: Probably CentOS 6 then. IIRC you can do a `rpm -qa centos-release` to confirm ([example](https://dpaste.de/rZ9k)) but that's almost certainly what it is. In that case there should be a `/etc/centos-release` file instead but for some reason the globbing didn't catch it. Weird.

Comment: -bash: rpm: command not found

-bash: /etc/centos-release: No such file or directory

Comment: Not sure then, it might be something Godaddy put together that's based off CentOS then. That's what Amazon did with Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 3):

From your output, it's a redhat based system. Your kernel has el6 in the name and gcc states `Red Hat 4.4.7-16`. This more than likely means it's **CentOS 6**.

Typically on Red Hat systems, these will give you a hint on what's installed:

- `/etc/redhat-release`
- `/etc/centos-release`
- `uname -r` => If the kernel has an `EL`* in the name, it's Enterprise Linux. The number will tell you the major release version

As an aside, your kernel is not a mainline kernel. Despite the fact that it has EL6 in the name, it also has a VERY different version number and has an LVE tag. Looks like this is a GoDaddy spun version of CentOS. They have a tendency to remove a lot of core functionality and binaries and hide them away from the users.

Comment: uname -r
2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64
So what's my Package Management?

Comment: @Hamza your package management will be rpm in Red Hat-land.

Comment: @chicks after talking in comments, I think they've removed `rpm` for some reason. It sounds like it's been stripped way down.

Comment: yes rpm also gives error for me.